# Binding enumeration to RadioGroup and CheckboxList via AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've 2 years knockoutjs experience, binding viewmodel to "radio group" or "checkbox list"  was always painful. I can see that it is also painful for angularjs.

These are sample typescript enumeration for binding :

```
enum Role {
    Student= 1,
    Teacher= 2,
    Principal= 4
}

class SingleSelect<T>{

}

class MultipleSelect<T>{
}
```

I need both RadioGroup (SingleSelect) binding and CheckboxList(MultipleSelect) 
Is there any straightforward approach for this requirement like this?

**Required Convention**

```
<checboxlist data="{{MultipleSelectionRolesContainerViewModel}}"> <checboxlist>
<radiogroup data="{{SingleSelectionRolesContainerViewModel}}"> <radiogroup>
```

SingleSelectionRolesContainer viewModel has selectedItems property.
MultipleSelectionRolesContainer viewModel has selectedItem property.

**EDIT**

Why binding a model to radio buttons is painful?

**1st approach**:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
  <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

**2nd approach**:

```
<label data-ng-repeat="act in activities">
<input
    name="currentActivity"
    type="radio"
    value="{{act}}"
    ng-model="engineer.currentActivity" />
    {{act}}
</label>
```

In summary,

**There is no angular directive like ng-options for radio group (for single select) and checkbox list (for multiple select)**

Comment: And now you add sample code you have tried?

Comment: use plugin link https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen just bind ng-model to elment

Comment: You should tell us your problem first before asking for a solution. And why do you think that binding a model to radio buttons is painful?

Comment: @pankajparkar yep this is useful but for "select" control. Multiple selection is not easy like "checkbox list".

Comment: @ozz  no..its easy.. only you just need to add multiple attribute inside select tag..here is eg http://jsfiddle.net/YKZSw/15/

Comment: @pankajparkar yes this sample is exactly what I mean. Only difference is I want to use CheckBox List  (for multiple selection), Radiogroup (for single selection)

Comment: @ozz Here is one more http://jsfiddle.net/hgxjv/4/

Comment: @ozz here is fiddle like something you want for checkbox selection http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/211/